# Using GDAL in Python class results in access violation (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, gdal, windows

I am getting Access Violation error when running (some) GDAL functions from a class method, while running a straight script works fine.

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) at point of failure, which corresponds to Access Violation.

Code that fails:

```
from osgeo import gdal

class GeotiffReader:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.bands = []
        self.read_geotiff()

    def read_geotiff(self):
        ds = gdal.Open(self.file_path)  # works
        band_count = ds.RasterCount
        for i in range(1, band_count+1):
            self.bands.append(ds.GetRasterBand(i))  # this works too

    def construct_nn_input_data(self):
        arras = []
        print(sys.path)
        for band in self.bands:
            arr = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, 500, 500)  # POINT OF FAILURE
            arras.append(arr)

        return arras


gtread = GeotiffReader("mapa_r_g_b_ir_mask.tif")  # or other multi-band tiff
gtread.construct_nn_input_data()
```

At the same time, when I simply define a method all works fine:

```
from osgeo import gdal

def read_arrs(file_path):
    bands = []
    ds = gdal.Open(file_path)
    band_count = ds.RasterCount
    for i in range(1, band_count+1):
        bands.append(ds.GetRasterBand(i))

    arras = []
    for band in bands:
        arr = band.ReadAsArray()
        arras.append(arr)

    return arras


read_arrs("mapa_r_g_b_ir_mask.tif")
```

I am sitting on a Windows 10 machine 64bit using Python 3.7.9 and GDAL 3.2.0 and am working on IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.

Digging deep with debugger at assembler level showed the program really tries to execute some random part of memory.

I have tried working with PATH system variables, resorted removing both Python and GDAL, clearing registries, re-installing basically from scratch.

Most odd to me is that it works (with exact same settings, sys-variables, python, etc.) if we call ReadAsArray from a method, but I cannot wrap the code in a class.

What am I missing?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Hello, yes, indeed I got victim of the [GDAL python gotcha](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-crashes-if-you-use-an-object-after-deleting-an-object-it-has-a-relationship-with).
All seems to work afer adding self.ds

Comment: Please don’t include answers in questions. I’ve rolled back your attempt to do so. If you think an answer was correct then just click the Accept button. You can self-answer in the area reserved for answers but in this case I don’t think that would be warranted.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR - assign the dataset object to an instance variable (`self.ds`)**

You have been bitten by a well known [GDAL python gotcha](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-crashes-if-you-use-an-object-after-deleting-an-object-it-has-a-relationship-with) (far too well known to long time GDAL python users... :).

Your `ds` dataset object is being deleted after it goes out of scope (exiting the  `read_geotiff` method) so any time you try and use `self.bands[...]` python crashes.  From the gotchas page:

> This problem occurs because the GDAL and OGR objects are implemented
> in C++ and the relationships between them are maintained in C++ using
> pointers. When you delete the dataset instance in Python it causes the
> C++ object behind it to be deallocated. But the C++ object behind the
> band instance does not know that this happened, so it contains a
> pointer to the C++ dataset object that no longer exists. When the band
> tries to access the non-existing object, the process crashes.

So assign the dataset object to an instance variable (`self.ds`) to keep it from being deleted after exiting your `GeotiffReader.read_geotiff` method.

```
class GeotiffReader:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.bands = []
        self.ds = None
        self.read_geotiff()

    def read_geotiff(self):
        self.ds = gdal.Open(self.file_path)  # works
        band_count = ds.RasterCount
        for i in range(1, band_count+1):
            self.bands.append(ds.GetRasterBand(i))
```

As a final remark, you may wish to consider switching from the GDAL python bindings to `rasterio` an alternative and more pythonic (and arguably more user friendly) interface to GDAL.

From the intro to [`rasterio`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html):

> Before Rasterio there was one Python option for accessing the many
> different kind of raster data files used in the GIS field: the Python
> bindings distributed with the Geospatial Data Abstraction Library,
> GDAL. These bindings extend Python, but provide little abstraction for
> GDAL’s C API. This means that Python programs using them tend to read
> and run like C programs. For example, GDAL’s Python bindings require
> users to watch out for dangling C pointers, potential crashers of
> programs. This is bad: among other considerations we’ve chosen Python
> instead of C to avoid problems with pointers.
>
> What would it be like to have a geospatial data abstraction in the
> Python standard library? One that used modern Python language features
> and idioms? One that freed users from concern about dangling pointers
> and other C programming pitfalls? Rasterio’s goal is to be this kind
> of raster data library – expressing GDAL’s data model using fewer
> non-idiomatic extension classes and more idiomatic Python types and
> protocols, while performing as fast as GDAL’s Python bindings.